# Postgresql - selecting observations and putting in new table

Tags: postgresql, text

Sorry if this has already been asked. I couldn't see it in previously asked questions.

I have a table - 'eightks'.

This file contains 1,000,000 text documents.

I only need those that mention the word 'other events'. So I am trying to do some text matching and then output these files into a new table.

My current code is;

```
 SELECT * FROM eightks\d
 WHERE to_tsvector(text) @@ to_tsquery('other_events');
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
    string is too long for tsvector (2368732 bytes, max 1048575 bytes)
```

Also How do I output the matching rows into a new table?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a [documented limitation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-limitations.html).

> The length of a tsvector (lexemes + positions) must be less than 1 megabyte

It might be possible to change the source code and recompile. See [ts_type.h](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/ts__type_8h_source.html). I suspect it won't be simple, though.

You might need to break the documents up into smaller pieces for searching, then combine the pieces for presentation to the user.

As for inserting the rows into another table, you can just insert a correct select statement. Basically . . .

```
insert into table_name 
select ...
```

You might need to supply column names.

Comment: Thanks @MikeSherrill. I didn't know this. Is there a way for me to specify only those observations below the size limit?

Comment: I don't think there's a easy way. Check the length with `length()`; store the keys for rows that have length < 1Mb in another table; join to it. (Store the keys so you don't have to repeat the calculation for every row in every query. The join will eliminate all the rows whose text is > 1Mb.)