# Postgresql - converting text to ts_vector

Tags: postgresql, textmatching

Sorry for the basic question.

I have a table with the following columns.

```
      Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
     --------+---------+-----------
      id     | integer | 
      doc_id | bigint  | 
      text   | text    |
```

- I am trying to do text matching on the 'text' (3rd column)
- I receive an error message when I try to text match on the text column. Saying that the string is too long for ts_vector.

I only want observations which contain the words "other events"

```
    SELECT * FROM eightks\d
    WHERE to_tsvector(text) @@ to_tsquery('other_events')
```

I know that there are limitation to the length of the ts_vector.

Error Message

```
   ERROR:  string is too long for tsvector (2368732 bytes, max 1048575 bytes)
```

How do I convert the text column into a ts_vector and will this resolve my size limit problem?Alternatively, How do I exclude observations over the maximum size?

Postgres version  9.3.5.0

Here is the reference to the limit [limit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-limitations.html)

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message? (**Always** include exact error message text, and PostgreSQL version, in your questions, along with the exact SQL run).

Comment: All done @craigringer. Sorry!

Comment: ... and the PostgreSQL version? Anyway: I wasn't aware `tsvector` had a size limit. Surprised me.

Comment: @CraigRinger ... eventually I will get it ;-)

Comment: @wazza2013 did you get to the bottom of this issue? I'm facing the same problem here.

Comment: How is this question different from your other one you asked one day earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715721/postgresql-selecting-observations-and-putting-in-new-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql - selecting observations and putting in new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715721/postgresql-selecting-observations-and-putting-in-new-table)

Comment: The [tsvector2](https://github.com/postgrespro/tsvector2) extension might be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal `ts_vector` size limitations is to split the documents in the `text` column into smaller chunks for searching, then merge the segments. After breaking the column you can store the chunks into separate rows or columns.

Another way to work around the `ts_vector` size limitations is to call `to_tsvector()` with a truncated text value. This can be achieved by creating a trigger function that sets the `ts_vector` column to a truncated text value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION tsv_trigger_fn() RETURNS 
trigger AS $$
begin
  new.tsv_text := to_tsvector('english', left(new.text, 1*1024*1024));
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tsv_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON <your_table> FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION tsv_trigger_fn();
```