# PostgreSQL: How to go around ts_vector size limitations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql, pg-search, tsvector

I'm creating a search inside a Rails app using the `pg_search gem`. However, one of the tables have a `Text` datatype field that it's content happens to be a little larger than usual.

Now when I need to setup a `tsvector column` for the `text` columns, I face some limitations that due the the text field size vs tsvector size.

`ERROR:  string is too long for tsvector (5068741 bytes, max 1048575 bytes)`

Is there any way that I determine condition to skip bigger `Text` fields while creating the tsvector column in the `SQL` trigger to do something like this:

pseudocode:

```
execute(<<-TRIGGERSQL)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.essays_before_insert_update_row_tr()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    If (SELECT LEN(body_text) FROM essays) <= 1048575
      new.tsv_body_text := to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.body_text,''));
      RETURN NEW;
    End
END;
$function$
  TRIGGERSQL

  # no candidate create_trigger statement could be found, creating an adapter-specific one
  execute("CREATE TRIGGER essays_before_insert_update_row_tr BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON \"essays\" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE essays_before_insert_update_row_tr()")
```

related question that I found without an answer:

[Postgresql - converting text to ts_vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716500/postgresql-converting-text-to-ts-vector)

Answer (score 8):

A simple workaround is to just invoke `to_tsvector()` with a truncated text value. For example, using the [trigger example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-UPDATE-TRIGGERS) from the Postgres manual as starting point this approach looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION essays_tsv_trigger_fn() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
    new.tsv_body_text := to_tsvector('english', left(new.body_text, 4*1024*1024));
    return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER essays_tsv_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON essays FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION essays_tsv_trigger_fn();
```

This truncates the document's content to 4 MiB which should be useful enough for many document collections. Instead of just ignoring 'overly' long documents you include at least parts of it. In my experience, 4 MiB works well for technical english documentation. Depending on the size of the actually used vocabulary you could even succeed when truncating with a larger value like 10 MiB.

If you really want to ignore too long documents you could guard the `to_tsvector()` assignment with an if statement like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION essays_tsv_trigger_fn() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
    if length(new.body_text) <= 4*1024*1024 then
        new.tsv_body_text := to_tsvector('english', new.body_text);
    end if;
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```